# I am trying to make a big list by using a present list but it's not working, can anybody explain why is this happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1=[0,1,2]
mega_list=[]
for x in range(4):
    print(list1)
    mega_list.append(list1)
    list1.pop(0)
    list1.insert(2,list1[1]+1)

print(mega_list)
```

Comment: What do you expect the final output to look like?

Comment: can you see the difference between mega_list and list1

Comment: why are elements in the mega_lists are all same in the output?

Comment: Do you really want list of lists? You need to create a copy of the `list1` on insert, e.g. `mega_list.append(list1[:])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are adding a *reference* to `list1` to `mega_list`. That is to say, at the end of the for loop you really have this:

```
mega_list = [list1, list1, list1, list1]
```

But, after the loop, `list1 = [4, 5, 6]`, so that's why you get the output:

```
[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

To fix this, make a copy of the list before iterating further:

```
list1=[0,1,2]
mega_list=[]
for x in range(4):
    print(list1)
    mega_list.append(list1.copy())
    list1.pop(0)
    list1.insert(2, list1[1]+1)
print(mega_list)
```

Which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the list, rather use the same instance in each append, e.g.:

```
list1=[0,1,2]
mega_list=[]
for x in range(5):
    mega_list.append(list1[:])
    list1.pop(0)
    list1.insert(2,list1[1]+1)

print(mega_list)  # [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

An alternative, is just use indexes into a full list of the input values, e.g.:

```
list1=list(range(7))   # [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
mega_list=[]
for i in range(len(list1)-3+1):
    mega_list.append(list1[i:i+3])

print(mega_list)  # [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

One alternative is to create a generalized `nwise()` function using `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it

def nwise(iterable, n):
    ts = it.tee(list1, n)
    for c, t in enumerate(ts):
        next(it.islice(t, c, c), None)
    return zip(*ts)

list1 = list(range(7))
mega_list = [x for x in nwise(list1, 3)]
print(mega_list)    # [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[0,1,2]
mega_list=[]

for x in range(4):
    # Adds list1 as an element
    mega_list.append(list1)
    # Increments each element of list1
    list1 = [x+1 for x in list1]
```

```
print(mega_list)
>>>[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```